# Sort Imported data without the header row Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I was just messing around with the IMPORTHTML function in Google Sheets. Very cool, but I realized I cannot sort the data without the header.

Here is a sample sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UXISF3-4hZPDBVbm56889156Zmeju81AbhUxgv2OxcE/edit?usp=sharing

This function is in A3:

```
=IMPORTHTML("https://www.investing.com/equities/"&lower(A2),"table",1)
```

It imports a nice table of data with the header, but say I want to sort it by `% chg (column G)`. If I wrap the function in a `sort()` it will also sort the header. I was thinking I could grab the data without the header but using `query({data}, "select * offset 1")` ignored the header so it just excluded the 1st line of useful data instead :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I have sorted by name (Col1), change ColX as you need

```
=query({IMPORTHTML("https://www.investing.com/equities/"&lower(A2),"table",1)},"select * order by Col1",1)
```

Comment: Doh :) I never thought to try Query sort. Thanks :)